# Integrating LinkedIn with openid

Tags: openid, integration, linkedin-api

Do you know some way to integrate LinkedIn with openid? I have a webpage that allows the users to login with openid and I was able to implement Yahoo, Facebook and Gmail.

Both Facebook and LinkedIn are not supported, as you may know, but I was able to integrate the facebook with the ffacebook connect method.

Do you know any method to integrate LinkedIn?